parser add_mutually_exclusive_group - how can I set a default value?
We use Python and Django for our websites. We set a test command that adds to the default Django test command:
from django.core.management.commands import test


class Command(test.Command):
    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        super().add_arguments(parser=parser)

        group = parser.add_argument_group('language options', 'These arguments are mutually exclusive. Default: --test-default-languages')
        language_group = group.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
        language_group.add_argument(
            "--test-all-languages",
            action="store_true",
            help="Run tests for all languages, and don't skip languages.",
        )
        language_group.add_argument(
            "--test-default-languages",
            action="store_true",
            help="Run tests for default languages (English, French, Hebrew + randomly select one more language or none).",
        )
        language_group.add_argument(
            "--test-only-english",
            action="store_true",
            help="Run tests for only English.",
        )

        # ...

Now, in the models we have this code:
    class SiteDiscoverRunner(DiscoverRunner):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            # ...
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.test_all_languages = kwargs.get('test_all_languages', False)
            self.test_default_languages = kwargs.get('test_default_languages', False)
            self.test_only_english = kwargs.get('test_only_english', False)
            if ((self.test_all_languages is False) and (self.test_only_english is False)):
                self.test_default_languages = True

Tests must be run with one of the above command line arguments or none. If none then the test_default_languages value should be true.
I would like to know if the parser can make self.test_default_languages True if none of the 3 arguments is given, so I can remove the command self.test_default_languages = True in the model? I searched and didn't find out how to do it.

A group does not have a 'default' value.  It just objects when you provide values for multiple arguments in the group.

@hpaulj Do you mean the parser can't set a default value for the group? Maybe it's worth requesting this feature for future versions of Python.

Look at the args namespace object.  You'll see values for the test_default_languages etc arguments, but nothing related to the group,  'language options'.  What you apparently want does not fit well with the group parsing logic.  Have you considered one argument with 3 string choices instead of the 3 boolean values?  One way or other you need some post parsing logic.

@hpaulj Thank you, I will think about it. In the meantime I added another option to the group, a string (or None) and you can see my updated code on https://github.com/speedy-net/speedy-net/blob/main/speedy/core/base/management/commands/test.py

I know that technically it's possible to use one argument with string choices but from the user perspective I think they will prefer to keep it as it is now.

I asked on discuss.python.org and got a reply, and I found a solution:
The test command:
from django.core.management.commands import test


class Command(test.Command):
    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        super().add_arguments(parser=parser)

        group = parser.add_argument_group('language options', 'These arguments are mutually exclusive. Default: --test-default-languages')
        language_group = group.add_mutually_exclusive_group()
        language_group.add_argument(
            "--test-all-languages",
            action="store_const",
            const="test-all-languages",
            dest="test_languages",
            help="Run tests for all languages, and don't skip languages.",
        )
        language_group.add_argument(
            "--test-default-languages",
            action="store_const",
            const="test-default-languages",
            dest="test_languages",
            help="Run tests for default languages (English, French, Hebrew + randomly select one more language or none).",
        )
        language_group.add_argument(
            "--test-only-english",
            action="store_const",
            const="en",
            dest="test_languages",
            help="Run tests for only English.",
        )
        language_group.add_argument(
            "--test-only-language-code",
            action="store",
            dest="test_languages",
            help="Run tests for only one language (the given language code).",
            type=str,
        )
        parser.set_defaults(test_languages="test-default-languages")
        # Running tests with --test-only-language-code en is equivalent to running tests with --test-only-english.

        # ...

And in the models:
    class SiteDiscoverRunner(DiscoverRunner):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            # ...
            super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.test_languages = kwargs.get('test_languages', None)
            # ...
            assert (self.test_languages in {'test-all-languages', 'test-default-languages', 'en', 'fr', 'de', 'es', 'pt', 'it', 'nl', 'sv', 'ko', 'fi', 'he'})
            # ...

Notice I also added the argument "--test-only-language-code". This is followed by the language code, for example "en".
